# How to give permissions to read write but not delete the file

Tags: permissions, files

i want to give users the ability to create write and read files in other user directory , but not to have option to delete the file after created ( sticky bit not going to work here ... ) 
for example :

```
i have user : manager  with directory repository  
i have user : worker1 that need to write files to /manager/repository  can't delete the files 
i have user : worker2 that need to write files to /manager/repository  can't delete the files  
i have user : worker3 that need to write files to /manager/repository  can't delete the files
```

but worker 1-2-3 can't delete the files after created only manager and root can delete the files worker 1 2 3 created.

i tried few chown and chmod tricks with stick bit 1 without success.

Comment: Standard Unix permissions won't let you do this directly...the only way to prevent a user from deleting their own files in a directory is to remove their write permission from the directory, but then the worker can't create in the directory. Not sure if this works in your environment, but you could remove this permission from your users, but create a setuid/setgid copy of touch to handle creation. You'd need to flesh this out and keep an eye on security, but it might solve your problem.

Comment: Can you please specify the operating system? Are we talking Windows or Linux?
In Linux you could use the sticky bit:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit

Comment: linux / redhat 6.5 
Stickybit wont work

Comment: Why not? If you set the sticky bit to the directory only the owner can delete files in it. You could then use setuid like this `chmod u+s /manager/repository` to force newly created files to have the same owner as the directory or setgid (`chmod g+s`) to force the same group as the directory.
Other than that you have to use ACLs.